# iPhone Photos Info ToolBar Separate Pop-Up Window

Tags: iphone, photos

I have the following issue: I know how to view info on a certain file in Photos via (i) Info ToolBar. It shows the date the file was created, one can add caption etc. However, once this window appeared as pop-up window instead of just the swipe up version. I could minimize/maximize and even move it around.

It is not too crucial to know but I was just annoyed that I could not reproduce behavior. Does somebody know a touch or swipe combination of how to get Photos Info ToolBar as a separate pop-up window on its own?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do here? Is this what you want or what you don't want : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5upU.jpg (click link to see image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ***tap (hold) and swipe up*** on a photo in the Photos app, you will get the “info popup” as you call it.

- on the iPad, it shows as a seperate modal (floating box) that can be positioned anywhere on the screen
- on the iPhone it shows up as a split screen - either from the bottom in portrait or on the side in landscape. These can’t be (re)positioned like you can on the iPad

Based on your description, the first is what you’re looking for.

Comment: Right, that's what works

Comment: Correct, the case number one is what I am after. However, I somehow managed to achieve the case number on an iPhone. Perhaps, it was some sort of "bug", not sure. I thought maybe it also a common feature on an iPhone and I only needed an accurate combination of taps etc. In any case, thanks a lot.